# How do I make Google script ignore empty cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

we have a script that upload items into a database. How can the script ignore cells that are blank?

```
//furnitureVariantOptions var furnitureVariantOptions = []; if (dr.getCell(i, 8).getValue() != "") { woodTypes = dr.getCell(i, 8).getValue().split(","); var items = []; woodTypes.forEach(item => { items.push({ "value": item.trim() }); })

var woodTypesObject = {
  "name": "Wood types",
  "values": items
};
furnitureVariantOptions.push(woodTypesObject);

}

if (dr.getCell(i, 9).getValue() != "") { fabricTypes = dr.getCell(i, 9).getValue().split(","); fItems = []; fabricTypes.forEach(item => { fItems.push({ "value": item.trim() }); })

var fabricTypesObject = {
  "name": "Fabrics",
  "values": fItems
};
furnitureVariantOptions.push(fabricTypesObject);

}

if (dr.getCell(i, 10).getValue() != "") { sizeTypes = dr.getCell(i, 10).getValue().split(","); var sizeItems = []; sizeTypes.forEach(item => { sizeItems.push({ "value": item.trim() }); })

var sizeTypesObject = {
  "name": "Sizes",
  "values": sizeItems
};
furnitureVariantOptions.push(sizeTypesObject);

}
```

Sometimes the variants are just wood types, thus fabrics and sizes are empty and we want to have the script ignore their cells and only read those with values.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    //checks to see if column one is empty
    if(r[0] === '') {
      Logger.log("column A is null");
    }
  });
```

Comment: I think you are missing a double quote.